# gltf 2.0 BoxTextured sample

Tags: gltf

I try to understand the data in the [BoxTextured Model](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/BoxTextured/glTF-Embedded/BoxTextured.gltf) for the TEXCOORD_0 accessor.

As seen [in the capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVBkr.jpg), the datas seems correct for POSITION and NORMALS but why values in the TEXCOORD_0 accessor aren't in range of "max": [ 1.0, 1.0 ], "min": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] but have a "max": [ 6.0, 1.0 ] ?

```
   {
       "bufferView": 2,
       "byteOffset": 0,
       "componentType": 5126,
       "count": 24,
       "max": [
           6.0,
           1.0
       ],
       "min": [
           0.0,
           0.0
       ],
       "type": "VEC2"
   }
```

Should those be normalized ?

My texture applied is totally wrong : [Rendered with uv test texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOZqV.jpg).
Where is my misunderstanding ?

Thank you
(I know I have a problem with my face orientation but that's another problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6.0 comes from the number of faces on the cube. Note that the sampler specifies REPEAT (10497):

```
    "samplers": [
    {
        "magFilter": 9729,
        "minFilter": 9986,
        "wrapS": 10497,
        "wrapT": 10497
    }
],
```

so the image will be tiled repeatedly. It's just a simple way to get the logo rendered on all six faces of the cube.

Comment: Thank u, I understand the repeat value in the sampler. what i don't understand is why uv's are ranged in that way (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVBkr.jpg) . If 6.0 in max comes from the number of face, why uv coords themself aren't between 0.0 ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Your screenshot shows vertices defining a cube, side by side, and each side is clearly given an UV span of e.g. (4, 0) to (5, 1), or (1, 0) to (2, 1). Since repeat is on, all such overflow UV coords will display the content of (0, 0) to (1, 1), which is the logo. If this is still confusing, can you describe what you expect to happen that doesn't happen?